# How would Boltzmann Brain function with all anti-matter in it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, cosmology, universe, antimatter

Please cope with me, I have been thinking about Boltzmann Brain yesterday and if [Quantum fluctuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation) always happen in pairs of particle and antiparticle since sum of all energy has to be 0.

My brain is made from matter only then how would it work with all the extra anti-matter in it?

Or my understanding that virtual particles have to be in close proximity is wrong, and what we would get is 'matter' brain and then identical anti-matter brain and they would annihilate?

**How does Boltzmann solve the anti-matter problem in Boltzmann Brain hypothesis?**

Comment: Right now an antimatter person in a parallel antimatter universe is thinking the exact same thing... stop it guys, you are going to interfere us all into oblivion! :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne It's anti-matter guys fault, he started it in the first place.

Comment: Let's just hope the two of you are sufficiently out of phase. ;-)

Comment: Btw antiparticles also have **positive** energy, which is a counterargument for the faulty logic of yours which you use in the first paragraph.

Comment: @Hindsight Hi, I don't see how this is relevant (doesn't mean that I am right). For brain (as I know it) to be 'functional' it should have one 'kind' of matter. Would you agree?

Comment: I don't understand what the anti-matter problem is supposed to be. It also seems to me that you misinterpreted a lot of things regarding quantum fiel theory (esp. quantum fluctuations)...

Comment: @Martin I am sure I did. However question is stupid at it's core. One being BB has to accept that his reality is illusion and logic stops to 'work' since you have learnt about rules through your fake experience and any further application of logic or sense is... Nonsensical? It's Catch 22.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius this is why they call it a comment (instead of an answer :) ). I simply wanted to emphasize that you have made a mistake and, probably, haven't realized it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

I was wrong to think that Boltzmann Brain requires to be made out of one kind of matter only - since I was basing it on my own understanding on how brain should be.

It does not matter what my understanding of brain is. If I am BB then whole my live is illusion and so are all my past memories that means that actual BB that fluctuate will function with matter and antimatter in it.

It does prove one thing though - if I am BB then I cannot be in the human (brain) form as I know it, nor a microchip the way we know them. Which is again wrong since I am basing it on my past memory about quantum fluctuations.

It's a dead end basically.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you would have to imagine a series of particle-antiparticle creation events, all arranged such that the matter particles all end up in the same place and form a "brain", while the antimatter ones all fly out away from them into empty space. This is fantastically unlikely of course, but then we're already talking about a fluctuation that can create a brain out of the vacuum, complete with a fake perception of a universe. Having all the antimatter conveniently fly away from it is fairly trivial compared to that.

Comment: Wouldn't this invalidate the fluctuation having to end in 0 sum energy?

Comment: Since we already have an infinite impossibility drive, we can as well produce an empty universe with a Boltzman brain that imagines an empty universe with a Boltzman brain imagining an empty universe with a Boltsman brain... imagining an infinite impossibility drive that creates...

Comment: More likely produces a kg of state machine that operates at near max efficiency as a computer and so simulates a few thousand Human brains and the sensory input suggesting there is a universe

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius that's a fair point. Perhaps you also have to imagine that the antimatter particles are emitted with sufficiently low velocity that they eventually return due to gravitational attraction, after the brain has done all its imagining of the universe, and then annihilate all the matter particles again.